# How do I change beat markers without warping audio in Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live

I am curious if it is possible to adjust the beat markers to match each beat in some live audio in Ableton Live. The problem I am having is I have some pre-recorded audio clip that wasn't played at one tempo, the tempo goes up and down throughout the song.

I understand I can use warp markers but this only warps my audio clip and adjusts the tempo. I do not want to warp or adjust the audio clips inherent tempo changes, rather the beat markers to match each beat so that I can play a metronome over the top that will speed up and slow down slightly keeping in time with the clip. Also I want to eventually record some midi drums over the top and quantize them to match the beats in time with the clip, so moving the beat markers will help with this.

This is how it works in Pro Tools by inserting tempo changes, is there any way this is possible in Ableton, or can I achieve this is a different way?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it is explicitly supported, and is easy to do once you know what it's called and where to click. What you want to do is make the clip the _tempo master_. Read the manual from Help / Read the Live Manual... Find a section about "Tempo Master/Slave" in chapter TEMPO CONTROL AND WARPING. Quote: "_The clip that is the current tempo master will play as if warping was off, but with one important difference – the rest of the Live Set will be warped so that it plays in sync with the current tempo master._"